# How do i tempoarily add a product to a category - woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have users who have specific products for each user, so i'm trying to add a "My Products" category, where each user can see their products

```php
    function my_products_cat( $q ) {

        global $post, $wpmem;
        $products = array();        

        $args = array(
            'limit' => 100,
        );
        $products = wc_get_products( $args );

        foreach($products as $product){
            if(wpmem_user_has_access($product)){
                $product->addToCategories("My Products");
            }
        }     
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'my_products_cat' );
```

*Note* I'm using wp-members to add some of the functionality. And for some reason 'pre_get_posts' crashes my site

I basically need the functionality to be able to tempoarily add a product to the "My Products" category

EDIT

Current progress:
I got it to only show the available products for the user. Now i need it to only work when on page 945 (page with woocommerce [products] shortcode), or when "My Products" category is selected. Either would be fine

```
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {
    if(is_page(945)){
        global $post, $wpmem;
        $posts = array();
        $ids = array();

        $args = array('post_type' => 'product',
                      'posts_per_page' => '-1',);
        $posts = get_posts($args);



        foreach($posts as $postss){
            $temppik = $wpmem->membership->get_post_products( $postss->ID );
            if(!wpmem_user_has_access($temppik)){
                array_push($ids, strval($postss->ID));


            }
        }

        $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );

        $tax_query[] = array(
               'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
               'field' => 'slug',
               'terms' => $ids,
               'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        );

        $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );
```

Comment: `addToCategories` isn't a method of the WC Product class. You might want to try `$product->set_category_ids( category_id_here)` and pass the ID of the created category.

Comment: @disinfor The problem is that "set_category_ids" is permanent, and i need to call "$product-save()" afterwards. I want the category to show products based on which user is logged in

Comment: I wouldn't use a category for this - why not use a meta field? Or even a transient?

Comment: With your working code, why not `if( is_page(945) || is_product_category( 'my-products' ) )`